# Preview images, and PDFs inside a SSH terminal session or inside emacsclient session via SSH?

Tags: ess, images, remote, previewing

I work remotely to Linux servers, writing R scripts with `ESS`. Rstudio works well if I have a fast and stable GUI-based remote desktop connection to the server. Rstudio server also works OK if I have the server running and now problems with managing logins. However, these two choices are not available on the server. So, Emacs+ESS is a great choice for code editing experience. The catch is, I will have to download generated images and PDF to my local computer to see them. That is not a workflow I want to do every couple of minutes. Doing a SSHFS mount to local computer is a better, but is still not the workflow I want. The ideal workflow:

1. Write code in an `emacsclient` inside a `tmux` session
2. Run code to generate plots, or PDFs from Rmarkdown
3. Preview the files right afterward inside the emacsclient window, or in another tmux split, or Window.

[This threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97542/how-do-i-make-my-terminal-display-graphical-pictures) discusses various options to view images in the terminal. There is [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) package for emacs to preview PDF documents. So, I believe it is technically possible at the moment. But I don't use emacs so frequent these days so my reflex is a bit rusty. Some guidance/demo setup code will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you run Emacs on your local machine, and open files on the remote machine via [Tramp](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/), you can view remote files as if they were on your local machine, you don't need to do anything special. ESS also uses Tramp to run an [R process on your remote machine](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers):

My workflow is:

1. open emacs locally
2. edit file on remote machine, via `C-x C-f /ssh:remotehost:myRScript.R`
3. start a new R process (either directly via `M-x R`, or by running a line from my script via `C-c C-n` etc

After this, you are editing in your local environment (with full graphical support), R is running on your remote machine, and Tramp manages the connection for you.

If you generate a plot, e.g.,

```
jpeg(file = "myplot.jpeg")
plot(1:25)
dev.off()
```

You can open it for viewing via `C-x C-f myplot.jpeg` from your script file.

If you use org mode, this is even easier: you specify the output file for each code block, and org will insert a link to that file after you run the code. Click the link, and the file (on your remote machine) opens in your local Emacs.